# In a for loop, if my iterator satisfies a condition, how can I pass to the next iterator?

Tags: python, for-loop, iterator, continue

I need some help with a `for loop`.

If i'm looping over a list of items using a `for` statement, how i'm supposed to **pass to the next iterator if the actual satisfies a condition?**

Example:

```
for item in list:
    if item == 10:
        next_item
    else:
        do_something
```

What should I write instead of `next_item` ?

Comment: use `continue` instead of `next_item`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`continue` will work. However, why not:

```
for item in list:
    if item != 10:
        do_something
```

Or even:

```
[do_something(item) for item in list if item != 10]
```

Comment: if they want to use the next value then this won't work

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, I'm 99% percent sure OP was just asking how to skip to the next iteration and didn't know what terminology to use.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you mean get the next item in the if, you can use iter calling next to get the next element from the list in the if statement:

```
lst = [1,2,3,4]
it = iter(lst)
for item in it:
    if item == 10:
        nxt = next(it,None)
    else:
        do_something
```

You might want to check `if nxt is not None` before doing anything with nxt, if you may have None's use object:

```
lst = [1,2,3,4]
obj = object()
it = iter(lst)
for item in lst:
    if item == 10:
        nxt = next(it, obj)
        if nxt is not obj:
            # do whatever
    else:
        do_something
```

Comment: one more time your answers cleared my way of seeing my problems and added some knowledge to me... heheh thanks @PadraicCunningham! But like ndn said, i was just looking for the specific terminology.